# Pre-image Id always equals target Id

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm writing a pre-update plugin for Dynamics CRM. Why does pre-image entity always have the same Id as target entity?

```
                var target = (Entity)localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"];

                var context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;

                Entity preImage = (context.PreEntityImages != null &&
                                   context.PreEntityImages.Contains(this.preImageAlias))
                    ? context.PreEntityImages[this.preImageAlias]
                    : null;

                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(target.Id + ";" + preImage.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

The pre-image, target, and post-image all represent the same record.  The pre is the record as it was prior to the core operation and the post is the target record after the core operation.  All three will always have the same id.